# A master URL must be set in your configuration gives lot of confusion

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have compiled my spark-scala code in eclipse.
I am trying to run my jar in EMR (**5.9.0 Spark 2.2.0**)using spark-submit option.
But when I run I get an error:

```
Details : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

After reading lots of StackOverflow solution I get confused and did not find a correct explanation of how and why to set app master.

This is how I run my jar.I have tried all below option

```
spark-submit --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark-submit --master yarn --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark-submit  --master yarn-client --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-client --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar

spark-submit --master local[*] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-submit --master local[1] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-submit --master local[2] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-submit --master local[3] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-submit --master local[4] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark-submit --master local[5] --deploy-mode cluster --class financialLineItem.FinancialLineItem s3://trfsmallfffile/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I am not setting any app master in my Scala code .

```
  package financialLineItem

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import java.sql.{ Date, Timestamp }
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

object FinancialLineItem {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("Enterin In to Spark Mode ")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FinanicalLineItem");
    println("After conf")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf); //Creating spark context
    println("After SC")
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._

     val get_cus_val = sqlContext.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))

    val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://path/FinancialLineItem/MAIN")
    val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
    val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
    val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)

    val schemaHeader = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "."), StringType)).toSeq)
    val dataHeader = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schemaHeader)



    val df1resultFinal = data.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))
    val rdd1 = sc.textFile("s3://path/FinancialLineItem/INCR")
    val header1 = rdd1.filter(_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
    val schema1 = StructType(header1.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
    val data1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema1)

    val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("LineItem_organizationId", "LineItem_lineItemId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc)
    val latestForEachKey = data1.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")

    val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinal.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("LineItem_organizationId", "LineItem_lineItemId"), "outer")
      .select($"LineItem_organizationId", $"LineItem_lineItemId",
        when($"DataPartition_1".isNotNull, $"DataPartition_1").otherwise($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"),
        when($"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId_1").otherwise($"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId").as("FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId"),
        when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, $"FFAction_1").otherwise($"FFAction|!|").as("FFAction|!|"))
      .filter(!$"FFAction|!|".contains("D|!|"))

    val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode", concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

    val headerColumn = dataHeader.columns.toSeq

    val headerLast = headerColumn.mkString("", "|^|", "|!|").dropRight(3)

    val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "|^|null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", headerLast)

    dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition", "StatementTypeCode")
      .format("csv")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .option("quote", "\u0000")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("codec", "gzip")
      .save("s3://path/FinancialLineItem/output")
```

Even i tried setting master url in spark-scala code.

**This is working in EMR example for spark**

```
spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar 5
```

If this working then why my jar is not working ?
I tried printing statement in my scala class before creating spark context and it is printing ,so there is no issue in jar file creation .

I don't know what am i missing ?

Updating my eclipse IDE setup also .
[image: Eclipse IDE set up]

Followed below docs

[AWS add steps document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html)

**This is what my observation**

*A master URL like "spark://..." is for Spark Standalone, but EMR uses Spark on YARN, so the master URL should be just "yarn". This is already configured for you in spark-defaults.conf,*

**More findings .**
When i tried to submit from spark-shell i got below error

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection.
```

I think there might some issue with my code also .

But i am getting correct result when i run it from `Zeppelin` .

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusion going on here in the question and in the first answer. If you're running on EMR, which runs Spark on YARN, you do not need to set a master URL at all. It automatically defaults to "yarn", which is the correct value when running Spark on YARN (as opposed to Spark Standalone, which would have a master URL like spark://:7077).

As mentioned in one of the other answers, "--master local" and "--deploy-mode cluster" also don't make sense together. "--master local" should only be used for local development and testing purposes and doesn't make sense to use on a cluster of machines such as on EMR. All it does is run your entire application in a single JVM; it won't run on YARN, it won't be distributed across the cluster, and there won't even be a separation between your driver code and the tasks.

As for "--deploy-mode cluster", as also stated in the other answer, this means that your driver runs in a YARN container on the cluster along with the executors, as opposed to the default of "--deploy-mode client", where the driver runs on the master node outside of YARN.

For more information, please see the Spark documentation, mainly https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), `--deploy-mode cluster` asks `spark-submit` to run the driver on one of the executors.

That, however, isn't applicable to your execution. as you're running locally. You should be using the `client` deploy mode. For that, just remove the `--deploy-mode` parameter altogether.

You have to choose one of the following calls, depending on how you want to run the driver program (or executors, for the last option). It's important to understand the differences as they are consequential.

If you want to run the driver program on the cluster (cluster mode, master chooses where on the cluster):

```
spark-submit --master master.address.com:7077 --deploy-mode cluster #other options
```

If you want to run the driver program on the compute that is calling spark-submit (client mode, executors remain on the cluster):

```
spark-submit --master master.address.com:7077 --deploy-mode client #other options
```

If you are running all locally (driver and executors), then your `local` master is appropriate:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] #other options
```

Comment: If you are not running locally, then you must specify the master URL: `--master master.address.com:7077`. These two conflict in your spark-submit call. Where's your master running? And is it started?

Comment: yes it is started ..i am running on EMR   `Master public DNS:ec2-24-2358-155-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @SUDARSHAN Added more call alternatives.

Comment: 'master.address.com:7077` would be my `ec2-24-2358-155-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com` right ?

Comment: I'd assume so. Just make sure that it's listening on port 7077 and firewall rules allow the machine you're running spark-submit from to connect on it.

Comment: How is it failing (what error is it raising)? Also, does this work when you run it locally (last option)? Does it work when you connect to your master's Web UI (by default: http://ec2-24-2358-155-38.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080)?

Comment: It is failing with same error ...and yes i am able to see the web ui ..All last failed application

Comment: Have you tried setting master url in your config? `new SparkConf().setAppName("FinanicalLineItem").setMaster("host:7077")`?  (Setter may be named differently)

Comment: yes i tried that too but same result ..Shared my code sample also